# Multiply all values in a sequence in Xquery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have the an xml document with the following structure:

```
<class>
    <element>1</element>
    <element>2</element>
    <element>3</element>
  </class>
  <class>
    <element>10</element>
    <element>82</element>
    <element>31</element>
  </class>
...
```

I want to return the result of multiplying all the elements for each class. I've tried to create a counter, multiply each element by the counter returning it, but i couldn't get it to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your own function, e.g.:

```
declare function local:multiplytail($seq, $i, $res) {
    if ($i le 0) then $res
    else local:multiplytail($seq, $i - 1, $res*number($seq[$i]))
};
declare function local:multiply($seq) {
    local:multiplytail($seq, count($seq), 1)
};

//class/local:multiply(element)
```

Comment: If you're processor supports XQuery 3.0 you could also use fn:fold-left(...) which is a bit more elegant imho.